# The Element is not Attached to the DOM error is displayed when I try to get the text from a list of Web elements after applying a filter

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

What I want to do is to access a web page that has some elements displayed in a grid and some buttons that implement the filtering functionality.
The problem is that when I get the list of elements and try to inspect their properties, the error "The Element is not Attached to the DOM" is thrown every time.
Nothing that I have tried seems to work.
What I noticed though was that after applying a filter, the grid with objects reloads with the filtered results and this may cause the error.
How I can get rid of this error?

This is the code that I have (I am using Page Objects):
// field container containing all the elements

```
    @FindBy(id = "MainContent_dtUnitsRepeaterDesktop")
        private WebElement gridContent;
        @FindBy(css = "div.sizes")
        private List<WebElement> unitSizes;

//method returning the list of web elements that hold the text I need
public List<WebElement> getUnitSizes() {
        List<WebElement> units = gridContent.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.sizes"));
        driverWaitObject.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElements(units));
        return units;
    }
//method that is extracting the text from each web element
public List<String> checkElementResults(List<WebElement> elemList) {
        for (WebElement elem: elemList) {
            unitType.add(elem.getText());
        }
return unitType;
}

// method to check and return
    public List<String> checkElementSizeResults() {
        return facilityPageObject.checkElementResults(facilityPageObject.getUnitSizes());
    }

As far as I have noticed the call that generated this error is at line "unitType.add(elem.getText());"
```

Any suggestions would be welcome (I am a beginner of Selenium WebDriver automation).

Comment: you have to repopulate the list after applying ht filter  , else use ispresent () to chekc whether  element is present

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Element is no longer attached to the DOM” StaleElementReferenceException when selecting HTML table row](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3464/element-is-no-longer-attached-to-the-dom-staleelementreferenceexception-when-s)

Comment: And also; [Element is no longer attached to DOM](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/15700/i-get-an-exception-element-is-no-longer-attached-to-dom-when-i-run-my-code-b), [StaleElementReferenceException](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/26299/staleelementreferenceexception-with-explicit-wait), [StaleElementReferenceException](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/29559/org-openqa-selenium-staleelementreferenceexception-stale-either-the-element-is)